# Shallow wall mounted cabinet - cabinet hanger vs french cleat

Tags: bathroom, walls, cabinets, hanging

I'm thinking of building a melamine cabinet for my bathroom to be fitted to the wall and I'm weighing up the different options for fitting it to the wall.

I'm thinking of the cabinet being 1800mm tall, 280mm wide and 250mm deep. It potentially end up with an 18mm door fitted.

The intended purpose is to have bathroom cleaning things in it, so it's not going to be overloaded with masses of weight.

This will be my first wall-mounted cabinet, and with it being a tall, thin one, I'm looking for some advice for the best way to fit it.

I have used french cleats before in my shed, and can make a piece to fit in the top of the unit to mate onto the wall piece. I have also seen [these Hafele cabinet hangers](https://www.toolstation.com/hafele-nylon-cabinet-bracket-plate/p96843) which I will have to drill the holes myself.

I'm assuming that these will have almost the same effect?

Another concern I had was that this cabinet being much taller than it is wide and having fixings just at the top... It might be easy to shift/swing on the wall. Is there a good way of securing it at the bottom to the wall also? Is it common that a french cleat or the Hafele hangers are applied down there also?

Comment: Why not direct attach it to the wall?

Comment: If you measure carefully you can use two French cleats. But screwing it to the wall studs is the norm if you're not likely to move it around (the usual reason for the workshop to use them - ease of rearranging.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usual approach I've seen is to use the French cleat together the cabinet hung on the wall, then drive a few screws through the back into the wall to keep it from moving. Though it would take a lot to kick a cabinet off a properly sloped cleat; the screws are largely to prevent sideways shifting, for cosmetic reasons, unless you expect earthquakes.